# Detecting and preserving original formats when extracting GIF frames with Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I separate and save the frames of a GIF with Pillow in the following way:

```py
from PIL import Image

def split_and_save_frames(gif_path):
    with Image.open(gif_path) as img:
        frame_count = img.n_frames
        
        for frame_index in range(frame_count):
            img.seek(frame_index)
            frame = img.copy()
            frame.save(f"frame-{frame_index+1}.jpg", "JPEG")
```

for example, I can save each frame as a .png file like this:
`frame.save(f"frame-{frame_index+1}.png", "PNG")`, and I can save each frame as a .jpg file like this: `frame.save(f"frame-{frame_index+1}.jpg", "JPEG")`. However, as you know, the frames can be composed of either .png or .jpg, and if I save a GIF composed of .jpg frames as .png, I may not get optimal results (either the file size would be too high or too low, there might be image loss, etc.). That's why I don't know whether to save as .png or .jpg when converting a GIF to frames. If I can learn the format of the frames that make up the GIF, I think I can save them accordingly, but I haven't figured out how to do it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

GIFs aren't composed of either JPEG or PNG frames - they are composed of GIF frames. Since GIFs can, and often do, include transparency, you're best off storing frames as PNG, since JPEG cannot store transparency.

Also, JPEG cannot store palette images (i.e. indexed images) as it only stores *"true-colour"* images (because it was developed for photographs), whereas GIFs always use the palette technique - another reason to use PNG which can also store palette images.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I completely agree with what you said. I'm already saving it as a PNG, but I just had this question on my mind.